# steps necessary to create and install the proper certificates and profiles into my project and onto my iPad/Phone

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, xcode3.2

I am hoping that someone on this list is working with iDevices, and has successfully built an application and loaded it onto their iDevice. If so, could you point me to any sort of 'distilled' explanation of the steps necessary to create and install the proper certificates and profiles into my project and onto my iPad/Phone so that I could install helloworld onto it? IU have been looking around the web, using Apple's documentation and videos, and not having any luck so far.

I need to get this working before I go to Big Nerd Ranch in a week, and right now feel like a deer in the headlights....

Thanks for ANY an all assistance!

Regards, and have a Safe and Happy Fourth weekend!

Steve O'Sullivan

Answer (score 0):

Well, in Xcode 3.2, it is much easier than in earlier versions. I was able to accomplish this by using the Observer.